# create view and joining 2 tables query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-view

I'm getting myself tied up in knots over this one, so hopefully, someone can help.

I need to create a view table and join 2 tables together, but I only need to display entries with missing data.

So, I have a table that lists drones I own, including the manufacturer, serial number and the date purchased, and I have another table that lists maintenance data, including the type of maintenance each device received. This table also includes similar data to the first table.

I need to pull the device data from the first table and compare that to the maintenance table and display the drones that have not received a particular type of maintenance.

This is what I have tried

```
CREATE VIEW uncommissioned AS
SELECT DISTINCT 
    drone.manufacturer AS manufacture, 
    drone.serial, 
    drone.type, 
    drone.purchase_date, 
    maintenance.type AS maintenance
FROM drone 
INNER JOIN maintenance ON drone.type = maintenance.type
WHERE maintenance.type = 'NULL';
```

But this gives an empty table, any suggestions on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: To note, the reason why you get no results is that you are using an `INNER JOIN` and trying to match  a `drone.type` to `NULL` (which I believe you intended a `NULL` "value" and not the string `"NULL"`). A `NULL` has no value and can't be equal to anything, even another `NULL`.

Comment: If `"This table also includes similar data to the first table."` means that you have duplicated data from the `drone` table, you might want to step back and look at your table design again.

Comment: @Shawn it's not my table design, its what I have been given to work with as part of an exercise :)

Comment: How does these tables relate to each other? I see it linking on `type`, but what does `type` refer to? Is that a Primary Key in `drones` or `maintenance`? Do you have an example of data that you're looking at?

Comment: @Shawn  so table 1 is drone, consists of Manufacturer (pri key), Serial (pri key) and type: drone_types      table 2 is maintenance, consists of manufacturer (pri key), Serial (pri key),  type: maintenance_type   if I query '''SELECT * FROM maintenance'''  I get a result of 5 drones that have had maintenance of varying types. If I query '''SELECT * FROM drone''' I get a result of 6 drones. So i need to write a query that gives me the 1 drone that hasn't had any maintenance.

Comment: So there is only one `maintenance` record for each drone? What is `serial` in both tables? They can't link on `type` because those values mean different things in the two tables. https://dbfiddle.uk/ works very well for that. Or http://sqlfiddle.com/.

Comment: Searches against Views in MySQL have limited access to underlying indexes making them, in my view, virtually useless. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want an anti-`LEFT JOIN`:

```
CREATE VIEW uncommissioned AS
SELECT DISTINCT 
    d.manufacturer AS manufacture, 
    d.serial, 
    d.type, 
    d.purchase_date, 
    d.type AS maintenance
FROM drone d
LEFT JOIN maintenance m ON d.type = m.type
WHERE m.type IS NULL;
```

Notes:

- to chek for nullity, you need the `IS NULL` construct (your code checks for litteral string `'NULL'`):
- if you want to display the maintenance type, you need to take that information from the `drone` table rather than from the `maintenance` table

You could also phrase this with a `NOT EXISTS` condition and a correlated subquery:

```
CREATE VIEW uncommissioned AS
SELECT DISTINCT 
    d.manufacturer AS manufacture, 
    d.serial, 
    d.type, 
    d.purchase_date, 
    d.type AS maintenance
FROM drone d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM maintenance m WHERE d.type = m.type)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response :)   The drone table contains no maintenance information, that resides solely in the maintenance table itself. All the drones except 1 have been commissioned, what I'm trying to do is pull out the ones that have had nothing at all, ergo, remain uncommissioned

Comment: @Khelmon: does the query produce the result that you expect?

Comment: it produces a populated table, but in maintenance column I see the drone types repeated

Comment: Just FYI: I'm not sure if MySQL behaves the same as SQL Server, but in modern versions, the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` method is usually faster.

Comment: @Khelmon Since you're essentially filtering out matching results from the `maintenance` table, just replace `d.type AS maintenance` with `'' AS maintenance`. You just need the empty string. Or just leave that column out all together. You don't really need it for the data you requested.

Comment: @Shawn  What I have is 6 drones purchased, 5 of those have been commissioned during a maintenance cycle.  The maintenance table contains the data for all maintenance cycles, and the drone tables contain all the purchased drones. What I'm attempting to do is create a view table that displays only those drones that haven't been commissioned as yet.  For me, it's an exercise in using JOIN, but it has been kicking my ass for the past 2 days :)

Answer (score 0):

IS NULL is right, and RIGHT JOIN because NULL in right table maintance
Try it:
    `SELECT DISTINCT drone.manufacturer AS manufacture, drone.serial, drone.type, 
    drone.purchase_date, maintenance.type AS maintenance
    FROM drone RIGHT OUTER JOIN maintenance ON drone.type = maintenance.type
    WHERE maintenance.type IS NULL;`

Comment: In my experience, a `RIGHT JOIN` is usually a `LEFT JOIN` that  should have been.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this also gave me an empty table :/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment:

Taking it step-by-step and building up what you want to do (we'll combine these sets later) ....

1. You're looking to check out all of your drones. So let's select columns from `drones` table to see what's there.

   ```
   SELECT * FROM drones ;
   ```

   > ```
   > manufacturer           | serial | type | purchase_date      
   > :--------------------- | -----: | ---: | :------------------
   > Lockheed Martin        |      1 |    1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00
   > Aerial Robotic Systems |      2 |   10 | 2020-02-01 00:00:00
   > Amazon                 |      3 |  100 | 2020-03-01 00:00:00
   > Northrup Grumman       |      4 |    2 | 2020-04-01 00:00:00
   > DJI                    |      5 |   20 | 2020-05-01 00:00:00
   > Titan Aerospace        |      6 |  200 | 2020-06-01 00:00:00
   > ```
2. What's in the `maintenance` table?

   ```
   SELECT * FROM maintenance ;
   ```

   > ```
   > dronetype | mxtype           
   > --------: | :----------------
   >         1 | Replace propeller
   >         1 | Commissioned     
   >       100 | Commissioned     
   >         2 | Commissioned     
   >        20 | Commissioned     
   >       200 | DECOMMISSIONED
   > ```
3. How do these two tables relate together? Let's hook them together
   with a `JOIN` on `type`. MOTE: I made an assumption and changed `maintenance.type` to be more descriptive of how I think these relations should be.

   3.1. Which `JOIN` do we need? ( For an illustration: https://www.edureka.co/blog/sql-joins-types). I'll only look at `INNER` and `OUTER` `JOIN`s.

   3.1.1 An `INNER JOIN` will only give us records that match in *BOTH* tables.

   ```
   SELECT d.manufacturer, d.serial, d.type, d.purchase_date, m.mxtype
   FROM drones d
   INNER JOIN maintenance m ON d.type = m.dronetype ;
   ```

   > ```
   > manufacturer     | serial | type | purchase_date       | mxtype           
   > :--------------- | -----: | ---: | :------------------ | :----------------
   > Lockheed Martin  |      1 |    1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | Replace propeller
   > Lockheed Martin  |      1 |    1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | Commissioned     
   > Amazon           |      3 |  100 | 2020-03-01 00:00:00 | Commissioned     
   > Northrup Grumman |      4 |    2 | 2020-04-01 00:00:00 | Commissioned     
   > DJI              |      5 |   20 | 2020-05-01 00:00:00 | Commissioned     
   > Titan Aerospace  |      6 |  200 | 2020-06-01 00:00:00 | DECOMMISSIONED
   > ```

   That's not really what we want.

   3.1.2 An `OUTER JOIN` will give us records from one of the tables and the rows that match in the other table. Unmatched rows will be `NULL`.

   ```
   SELECT d.manufacturer, d.serial, d.type, d.purchase_date, m.mxtype
   FROM drones d
   LEFT OUTER JOIN maintenance m ON d.type = m.dronetype ;
   ```

   > ```
   > manufacturer           | serial | type | purchase_date       | mxtype           
   > :--------------------- | -----: | ---: | :------------------ | :----------------
   > Lockheed Martin        |      1 |    1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | Replace propeller
   > Lockheed Martin        |      1 |    1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | Commissioned     
   > Amazon                 |      3 |  100 | 2020-03-01 00:00:00 | Commissioned     
   > Northrup Grumman       |      4 |    2 | 2020-04-01 00:00:00 | Commissioned     
   > DJI                    |      5 |   20 | 2020-05-01 00:00:00 | Commissioned     
   > Titan Aerospace        |      6 |  200 | 2020-06-01 00:00:00 | DECOMMISSIONED   
   > Aerial Robotic Systems |      2 |   10 | 2020-02-01 00:00:00 | null
   > ```

   ```
   That shows us all of the `drones` with a `NULL` record for the non-matched one.
   ```
4. But we want to show drones that haven't been `Commissioned` yet in the `maintenance` table.

   ```
   SELECT d.manufacturer, d.serial, d.type, d.purchase_date, m.mxtype
   FROM drones d
   LEFT OUTER JOIN maintenance m ON d.type = m.dronetype 
   WHERE m.mxtype <> 'commissioned' ;
   ```

   > ```
   > manufacturer    | serial | type | purchase_date       | mxtype           
   > :-------------- | -----: | ---: | :------------------ | :----------------
   > Lockheed Martin |      1 |    1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | Replace propeller
   > Titan Aerospace |      6 |  200 | 2020-06-01 00:00:00 | DECOMMISSIONED
   > ```

   But now we're missing our unmatched record, and we're showing records we don't want (like the `Lockheed Martin` record, which has 2 `maintenance` records with one being `Commissioned`).
5. So let's choose records from our `drones` table that *don't* have a `Commissioned` record in `maintenance`. We can do that with a `NOT EXISTS`.

   ```
   SELECT d.manufacturer, d.serial, d.type, d.purchase_date
   FROM drones d
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1 /* This can be anything. It's ignored. */
       FROM maintenance m 
       WHERE m.mxtype = 'commissioned' 
          AND m.dronetype = d.type
    ) ;
   ```

   > ```
   > manufacturer           | serial | type | purchase_date      
   > :--------------------- | -----: | ---: | :------------------
   > Aerial Robotic Systems |      2 |   10 | 2020-02-01 00:00:00
   > Titan Aerospace        |      6 |  200 | 2020-06-01 00:00:00
   > ```

   Now we've got the two drones that don't have a record in `maintenance` for being `Commissioned`.

   *NOTE: In this final query, we used a correlated subquery to link the `maintenance` table to the `drones` table, and we included a condition on our query for the `maintenance` table to only select records with `mxtype` or `commissioned`. And the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` will filter the query of the `drones` table to exclude any rows that DO have a match in the subquery.*

You can play with the query and data here: *[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=14a76212cb89c594d6b119d7fe534ef2)*